# Spring AMQP MessageListenerAdapter - How to split response into multiple messages?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-amqp

Is it possible to split the response of the `delegate` from `MessageListenerAdapter` into separate messages?

```
public class MyBean {    
  public List<Response> handleMessage(final MyPayload payload) {
    return ...
  }
}

...

@Bean
public MessageListenerContainer container() {
    final SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = containerFactory.createListenerContainer();
    container.setListenerId("myListener");
    container.setQueueNames("myQueue");

    final MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(new MyBean(), new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    listenerAdapter.setResponseExchange("");
    listenerAdapter.setResponseRoutingKey("other");
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    return container;
}
```

Adapter puts one message to the 'other' queue as expected, but I would like to split the response and send multiple messages for each item in the resulting `List<Response>`. Is this possible OOTB? Should I write a custom `MessageConverter` to support this?

Comment: Yes, why not just add a `splitter` down stream from your adapter? Is that what you're looking for? I mean that is the most natural way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; it's not supported; a request returns a single reply only.

The client side would be tricky to code too - how would it know how many responses are expected? The `RabbitTemplate` certainly doesn't handle multiple responses.

If you really want to send multiple responses, use a `RabbitTemplate` to send the replies on the server side and don't use request/reply messaging.

Comment: I am trying to send the responses to a static queue, I am not interested in request/reply mechanism, so my approach might be wrong. When I consume a message from RabbitMQ, I need to search for some files on my system and send a new Message per file. Is `MessageListenerAdapter` the wrong class for this?

Comment: It's the right way to invoke a POJO method with the decoded payload, but if you want to "reply" with multiple messages, you should return `void` and send the "replies" using a `RabbitTemplate` instead of using the built-in mechanism to send the method return value in a message (which simply uses a `RabbitTemplate` internally to send that reply).